# HTML mp4 Streaming / How can I automatically move the "atom moov" to the beginning of the file?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am currently building a Website for School and implemented an Upload-System. Now I want People to be able to watch uploaded Videos. Currently if you try to watch a Video, lets say **test.mp4** it takes over a minute to load.

I know that using:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mp4 -movflags faststart -acodec copy -vcodec copy outputvideo.mp4
```

moves the **atom moov** to the beginning of the file. And when I manually convert the mp4 using the previous command the file starts playing instantly.

**Problem:**
I don't want to convert each file manually. Is there another way of playing user-uploaded Videos instantly? Thanks for your help in advance.

*I am using this Code, but it has nothing to do with the streaming itself I guess:*

```
  <source src="Clap.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag. <!-- Text to be shown incase browser doesnt support html5 -->
</video>
```

*I also tried to use a js library:*

```
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="Clap.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

In both cases I want to play **Clap.mp4**

Comment: I've removed the `FFmpeg` tag since you're question is about NOT using it.

Comment: Ok @VC.One Im sry for using it

Comment: PS: You're probably not getting an answer because it's not feasible at this stage. To do this on file load, you need a system that can extract the ending MOOV (metadata) bytes (do a **range-request**) such as PHP on your server, then you need to edit the bytes (numbers) of the metadata to update them with new positions etc since metadata will now be at the front, so frame 1 bytes are moved to a new pos). Then finally stitch the new bytes and feed to a video tag. Look at **MP4 header specifications** to learn which atom values must be edited.

Comment: Another way would be again to do a range-request and extract the metadata. Then read it yourself to extract frames (audio or video) and feed them (as byte arrays) manually to a video tag using **Media Source Extension** methods.

Comment: if you are managing the upload, presumably you can script what's happening? php etc can call ffmpeg and perform the faststart for you

Comment: I am not extremely familiar with php, but nice to know that that's a thing :D I will do a bit more research on how to do it

Comment: so f.e with `exec("ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mp4 -movflags faststart -acodec copy -vcodec copy outputvideo.mp4")` right? or `exec_shell()`